# ubuntu 15.10: How to set alt+tab to switch windows only in the current workspace?

Tags: shortcuts

I know there are a lot of answers on the Internet, but I found that they were a little old and didn't work any more. I'm using 15.10, is there a way to set `alt+tab` to switch windows only in the current workspace?

Comment: Are you using gnome or unity? Gnome has an inbuilt extension under GNOME tweak tools to let you do just that. Using Ubuntu GNOME 15.10

Comment: I prefer this one though https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/310/alt-tab-workspace/

Comment: @AshharHasan Thank you. I'm using unity. But I found out that I could set it under unity-tweak-tool, and it worked. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I could set it under unity-tweak-tool

[image]